# CSS Keyframe Animation : Immediate background position change

Tags: css, animation, keyframe

I am creating a CSS keyframe animation in which I would like the background to change positions immediately with no transition. I've seen an example of this where two keyframes were used with the same value but I can't recreate the effect, I still get a smooth transition.

Here is my code http://jsbin.com/EvAHAKO/1/edit

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im not quite sure if this is what you want: http://jsbin.com/EvAHAKO/5/edit

Use two animations: http://jsbin.com/EvAHAKO/8/edit

Comment: Yes and no :) I'd like the movement to be animated but the background-position change to be instant at 50% of the item's trajectory.

Comment: Well, I think you'll have to use two animations.